# E488: Trailing characters in Vim mapping

Tags: vim, makefile, mapping

I want to map F5 on a command and typed:

```
:cmap <F5> :make | vert copen 100<CR>
```

Then I get E488. What to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Escape your `|`:

```
:cmap <F5> :make \| vert copen 100<CR>
```

Right now it tries to

```
cmap <F5> :make
and then 
vert copen 100<CR>
```

Escaping the `|` delimiter ensure your mapping is preserved.

Be aware that the `\|` escaping may not always work, as stated in `:help map_bar`. Alternatives are: `<Bar>` and `^V|`.

Thanks @Randy Morris.

Comment: Thank you. If I don't want to type `:` everytime before F5 works, I can simply stay on `:nmap`

Comment: yes, `cmap` is the command line mapping, whereas `nmap` is the normal mapping. Worth reading `:h mapping`

Comment: There are cases where escaping the bar with `\|` will not work.  See `:help map_bar` for other alternatives.